# How to call one Script function from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to validate Required fields in **`Java script`**. It will works fine on `Chrome`,`Firefox`.But it will not works for **Textbox** in `IE` at the same the **scripts** was works on `DropDownlist` validation on Submit button Click.

### My Script For Validate Text Box:

```
function validateRecepitMaster() {
    if ((!IsBlank(Pay_Amount))) {
            ShowLabel(spPay_Amount);
             spPay_Amount.innerHTML = "*";
            Pay_Amount.focus();
            return false;
        }
}

function IsBlank(obj) {
    if (obj) {
            if ((obj.value.trim().length == 0) || (obj.value == null)) {
            obj.focus();
            return false;
        }
       return true;
    }
}
```

The Working Script for DropDown

```
if (Cust_Id.value == "") {
        ShowLabel(spCust_ID);
        spCust_ID.innerHTML = "*";
        Cust_Id.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Above Both scripts woks fine on `Chrome, Firefox`, and not works at `IE`.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below script before run yours:

```
  String.prototype.trim=function()
{
     return this.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, '');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your console for the error that IE throws.

A possible candidate is:

```
obj.value.trim()
```

IE might not support `trim` (yet)

Comment: Ok..thanks..Is it any alternate solution for that sir

Comment: Not unless you give us more info and tell us what Error IE gives you.

Comment: Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 115
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:9149/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: @PraveenS, You can add trim function if its not negatively supported as `if (!String.prototype.trim) { String.prototype.trim = function () { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); };}`